# Rotating screen loses search

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, android-app

If you do a search on the Android app, then (in my case, accidentally) rotate the screen, your search is lost and it goes back to the unfiltered question list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed in 0.1.87 coming out around midnight UTC, thanks!