# The Android app Back button does not return me to my search results

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, android-app

In the Android app, if I do a search, tap a result, then tap back to try a different question, I'm returned to the unfiltered question list.

Worse, if I do a search for a user, tap a result, then hit back I end up on the question list (not even the user list).

Comment: I can't remember the last time I used the back button in a browser.  Oh, yes I can; it was with Yahoo Mail, and it was broken.  No internet site works correctly with the back button.  They all say "This page has expired."

Comment: Still, android has a back button, so it should work.

Comment: @Robert this is in reference to the Android App, where "back" is a built-in standard action, not the website

Comment: What version of the app are you using? On 0.1.85 this already happens for me.

Comment: @Kasra just downloaded latest, the question search works but user search still sends me to the wrong place

Comment: @DavidFullerton Yay I can see that one too, on it! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Boy, this and its [related counterpart](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216271/rotating-screen-loses-search/216305#216305) were a rabbit hole. The application was actually creating a new set of possible views (Questions, Tags, Users) each time you rotated the device and sticking it directly on top of the old one, so while the version of the view behind the one you were looking at did remember your place the one you could actually see did not.

This is fixed in version 0.1.87 coming out around midnight UTC, thanks!

As a side note: You might see a related issue where when you go back to questions or users it retains the search query but not the data. This is an edge case that happens when the phone runs out of memory so it ditches the contents of the list that are no longer in view, therefore we need to refresh.