# Going back twice required to return to search results in the tags view

Tags: bug, android-app

This looks a little bit like a variation on [The Android app Back button does not return me to my search results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216272/the-android-app-back-button-does-not-return-me-to-my-search-results) but specific to the tags view.

Reproduction (app version 1.0.71):

1. Select any site (say Meta) from the sidebar
2. Switch to the tags view using the top bar
3. Choose a tag, any tag ([android-app](/questions/tagged/android-app) is nice)

   - optionaly refine your search with more terms
4. Go to any question found, go back

   - you end on the unfiltered tags view
5. Go back again

   - lucky you, your search is here

Comment: Still repro'd on v1.0.73 (beta).

Comment: Still exists on Version 1.0.83 (beta), Galaxy S4. Although, it was driving me nuts until I saw from this question that going back one more time brings me to where I wanted to be.

Comment: Still exists in version 1.0.89 and it will still exist in any version, since nobody is working to fix any bugs in the android app.

Comment: You can always hold the back button and it will present you with the list of what it remembers, so you can pick the one you want directly.

Comment: Still an issue in 1.0.95. Also, @SDsolar, this is about the Android app, not the browser.