# Returning to search by tag from individual question

Tags: bug, android-app

I noticed that I can't return to the search results by tag when viewing questions. I have to re-enter the search criteria each time.

Recreate as follows:

1. Go to question search by tag.
2. select tag(s)
3. select one of the questions.
4. attempt to return to search results.

These actions return you back to the tag select page, not search results. This happens using the phones back button or on screen return button.

Comment: Woops. Looks like this was reported already. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/264248/304943