# Orientation change causes selected Tags to disappear

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, android-app

I observed this bug in version 1.0.73 of the android app. These are the steps to follow in order to replicate it.

1. From the navigation drawer select any site.
2. Once you see the set of newest question, from the action bar list select the    tags which will show you a list of tags for those sites. From that select any one tag .
3. We can see a list of filtered question based on the tag, now change the orientation of the phone. At this moment the selected tag disappears and so does the filtered set of questions.

Comment: Step one doesn't have to go through the navigation drawer

Comment: oh i just observed it this way you can edit to post the other scenario also

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264248/going-back-twice-required-to-return-to-search-results-in-the-tags-view?rq=1. After changing the orientation, you will be back to tag lists screen again, but pressing back will close the screen and back to filtered set of questions (based on previous tag you have selected)